# what type of data does flann index need by using LshIndexParams?

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

I want to use LSH to speed up the searching,and i found in opencv flann can do this,by using LshIndexParams? The problem is i cannot get the format right. i use bag of words to generate a 
mat output and feed it to flann, but i get errors all the time.

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=2
```

) in buildIndex_, file /home/vampire/opencv-2.4.8/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/vampire/opencv-2.4.8/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:315: error: (-210) type=2
 in function buildIndex_

part of the code likes this:

```
    Mat img_BOWdescriptor=BOW_descriptors(path);
cout<<img_BOWdescriptor<<endl;
img_BOWdescriptor.convertTo(img_BOWdescriptor,img_BOWdescriptor.rows,img_BOWdescriptor.cols,CV_32F);
cout<<img_BOWdescriptor<<endl;
cout<<"done"<<endl;

cout<<"ini flann index......"<<endl;
Mat indices = Mat(img_BOWdescriptor.rows, 1, CV_32S);
Mat dist = Mat(img_BOWdescriptor.rows, 1, CV_32F);
descriptors_all.convertTo(descriptors_all,descriptors_all.rows,descriptors_all.cols,CV_32F);

flann::Index* flann_index=new flann::Index(descriptors_all,flann::LshIndexParams(20,10,2));
cout<<"done"<<endl;
double t=(double)getTickCount();

cout<<"flann matching......"<<endl;
flann_index->knnSearch(img_BOWdescriptor, indices, dist, 1,flann::SearchParams(32));
```

and i also tried to convert to other type, no one works, does any one know how to do it?
and after i get result,how can i know if it matches?

Comment: get same problem as yours, have you got the solutions?  Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0
) in buildIndex_, file /Users/alexandershishkov/Downloads/opencv-2.4.8/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315

Comment: maybe vectors must be binary?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try. I think i had the same error, Mine works with an extra parameter:

```
cv::flann::Index kVecinos(descriptors, cv::flann::LshIndexParams(12, 20, 2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);
```

in cvflann there is also others like `cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN`